# XSD: Can I make an element inherit an ancestor's rules?

Tags: xsd

Consider the following:

```
<xs:complexType name="A">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:group ref="subAGroup"/>
        <xs:group ref="xGroup"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="B">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:group ref="subBGroup"/>
        <xs:group ref="xGroup"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

What I want to happen is if one of the elements in the xGroup is a child, grandchild, etc. of A then its children must be part of the subAGroup or xGroup.  If B is its ancestor then its children must be in the subBGroup or xGroup.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you're trying to accomplish and why? Something close enough to the real world for others to grasp. Your question is too abstract for me (though perhaps not too abstract for the real XSD experts, I admit).

Comment: @John - Please see the answer I posted. Does it still not make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to create different groups and types for each parent type.  To follow the example above, it would become this:

```
<xs:complexType name="A">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:group ref="subAGroup"/>
        <xs:group ref="xGroup"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="B">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:group ref="subBGroup"/>
        <xs:group ref="yGroup"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:group name="xGroup">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="Element1" type="AEleType"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:group>
<xs:complexType name="AEleType">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:group ref="subAGroup"/>
        <xs:group ref="xGroup"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:group name="yGroup">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="Element1" type="BEleType"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:group>
<xs:complexType name="BEleType">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:group ref="subBGroup"/>
        <xs:group ref="yGroup"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

It seems overly verbose though. Is there a more elegant solution?